# Calling an action from Html.DropDownListFor() ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down that needs to trigger a Url.Action with the id value that has been clicked

Currently I have:
Model

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Portal.Models
{
    public class CompanyViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompaniesList { get; set; }
    }
    public class CompanyViewModelDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CompanyViewModel> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model Portal.Models.CompanyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowDropdown";
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.CompanyList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "CoId","CompanyName"), Url.Action("SelectCompany", "Home", new { partnerCoId = "CoId" }, null))
```

Controller methods

```
 public PartialViewResult ShowDropdown()
        {
            var coid = Lt.GetThisUsersCoId();
            var model = new CompanyViewModel(); 
            using (var dc = new CompanyViewModelDbContext())
            {
                var content =
                    (from cr in db.CompanyRelationship
                        //This is grabbing all related companies to the logged in user
                        join c in db.Companies on cr.CoId equals c.CoId
                        where cr.PartnerCoId == coid
                        select new
                        {
                            cr.CoId,
                            c.CompanyName
                        }).Distinct().ToList();

                ViewBag.CompanyList = content;

                foreach (var item in content)
                {
                    model.Id = item.CoId;
                    model.CompanyName = item.CompanyName;
                }

            }

            return PartialView(model);
        }



public ActionResult SelectCompany(int partnerCoId, string redirect)
        {//Bunch of code that I didn't write but just needs to be triggered on click
```

The drop down should list a bunch of companies based on a global value, after one is select it sets up a relationship.

**What I am trying to accomplish**: Trigger the ActionResult SelectCompany based on what is chosen from the drop down.  Currently it doesn't seem to do anything, is there any good debugging tools I should be using in VS to see what happens when I click the drop down.  From my front end it appears as if nothing happens when I select a company.

**UPDATE**
I have gotten the script call into my View but I am having trouble using the @url.Action from within it, I have to pass this:

```
@Url.Action("SelectCompany", "Home", new {partnerCoId = x})
```

The value selected from the drop down.

Comment: Are you open to JQuery?

Comment: I have zero experience with JQuery but I'm willing to learn, I thought this would be the simplest way to implement some one else's code.  I am cleaning up multiple unnecessary calls that were being made, and trying to configure this drop down in as few lines of code as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery `Change()` event of dropdownlist.

The Simplest Way to achieve this is :

Place the below code in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.CompanyList as System.Collections.IEnumerable,"Select", new { @id = "dropdwonId" })%>

<script>
    $("#dropdwonId").change(function() {       // This will fire when the dropdown value will get changed
         var url = "YourUrl/" + $(this).val(); //Append Id To URL
         window.location.replace(url);         
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How do I link a dropdownId from an `@html.DropDownList()`? what I am doing with the Action is not changing the page, just changing what data is then displayed in a grid below based on a relationship.  I am really not sure how this will function with what I am doing.  Does this JQuery go in my View? Also, will I have to restructure all the work I have already done to implement this?

Comment: See the updated code. you can place jquery inside `<script>` block or you can place the jquery code in tour `.js` file.

Comment: Getting a "Cannot resolve id 'dropdownId'". This may be caused by the `new { @id = "dropdwonId" }` as it's giving me a string error.

Comment: Could this be caused by dropdownId, not being found in my model or ViewBag?

Comment: I am working with what you posted, thank you, and i'm trying to figure out how to get `Url.Action("SelectCompany", "Home", new { partnerCoId = "CoId" }` to function from within the JQuery

Comment: dropdownId is just an id you give to your controll. Its not required it to be present in your model or viewbag?
Is It Now Working for u?

Comment: No this isn't working for me, but it is more or less because of my inexperience with JQuery:
I need it to just be JQuery reads the value from the drop down and fires that Url.Action request.  But this is proving difficult, I am not sure how to trace what is happening with the drop down.